# The label does not change its size in the user element. (extends Control)

Tags: javafx, canvas, label, resize, controls

I need to make a custom element consisting of several elements. One of these elements is the `Label`. But this label does not set its size regardless of what is specified in the `setPrefMinSize`,`setPrefSize`, `setPrefMaxSize` methods. If you add a `Canvas` element, it is drawn normally.
Test method:

```
public class LinearMarkerTest extends Control {
    double width = 100.0;
    double height = 50.0;

    public LinearMarkerTest() {
        Label label = new Label("Label text");
        label.setMinSize(width, height);
        label.setPrefSize(width, height);
        label.setMaxSize(width, height);
        getChildren().add(label);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(100,100);
        GraphicsContext graphicsContext = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        graphicsContext.setFill(Color.RED);
        graphicsContext.fillRect(0, 10, width, height);
        getChildren().add(canvas);
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: from Region doc: _By default a Region inherits the layout behavior of its superclass, Parent, which means that it will resize any resizable child nodes to their preferred size, but will not reposition them_ - control does nothing more when it comes to layout, typically, that's the responsibility of its skin. Anyway, what do you want to achieve? Why the extension (vs. using one of the available layouts)?

Comment: When using custom elements extended from the layouts in the Scene Builder, the Scene builder inserts the elements inside these elements, whereas when using elements extended not from the layouts does not occur. Perhaps there is an easy way to prohibit add elements inside other objects in the Scene Builder?

Comment: Are you expecting the letters in the label to get bigger or smaller when the size changes?  I don't think it will do that.  You'll probably need to scale the label based on the width/height, which is a transformation.

Comment: This is a test case. I expect the `getWidth()` method and the `getHeight()` method to return the set size. But it returns zero.

Comment: I've never seen anyone try to extend Control before, but I think that is your problem.  First, I get an error that there's no CSS entry for -fx-skin for the class, and no createDefaultSkin() method.  So that's probably a big issue.  If you change the class to extend Pane, then you actually get the Label on the window (you have to set layout X & Y for it), and it will respond with the width.

You don't describe the nature of your custom control, but you'd probably be best off building it based on one of the container classes like, Pane, StackPane or VBox.